# Is it possible to insert cells into another sheet in Google Sheets through script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google-Sheet script that creates few cells and inserts them into active sheet. I would like to ask someone for help. I would need the script to do exactly same work, but only change I would need is to pick the sheet where the cells will be added. At this moment it always applies to the active sheet.

As you may recognized I am absolutely noob in coding and also in English, so I really appriciate everyone who tries to help me with this.

Thank you very much, Petr
The code I have right now:

```
function myButton(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range = sheet.getRange("A3:D3");
    range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = ss.getActiveRange();
    var R = range.getRowIndex();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modification patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

When you want to select the specific sheet in the active Spreadsheet, you can modify your script as follows.

```
function myButton() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Added. Please set the sheet name you want to select.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Modified
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:D3");
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var R = range.getRowIndex();
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to select the specific sheet in the other Spreadsheet from the active Spreadsheet, you can modify your script as follows.

```
function myButton() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Added. Please set the spreadsheet ID you want to use.
  var sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Added. Please set the sheet name you want to select.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId); // Modified
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Modified
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:D3");
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var R = range.getRowIndex();
}
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, from `I would need the script to do exactly same work, but only change I would need is to pick the sheet where the cells will be added. At this moment it always applies to the active sheet.`, it supposes that your script works fine for the 1st tab in the active Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.
- When `getSheets()` is used, for example, in the case of `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`, it's the 1st tab. In the case of `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];`, it's the 2nd tab.

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Thank you very much. First solution works pretty fine for me. Have a nice day, Petr